# Angular 2 Alerts that work with Bootstrap 4, similar to Toastr

Tags: angularjs, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am attempting to get toastr style alert messages working with Bootstrap 4 and Angular 2 and the current packages that I have installed only work with Bootstrap 3.

Wondering if anyone has had any success getting an alerts package working with Angular 2 and Bootstrap 4?

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster
- https://github.com/scttcper/toastr-ng2
- https://github.com/akserg/ng2-toasty

They all work as far as sending alerts to the screen and disappearing, but without any styling as the wrong classes are being used.

**I am using Bootstrap 4 and also ng-bootstrap in this project.**

[image: Un-Styled Toaster Message]

Comment: As far as I know... Toastr is not dependent on bootstrap. Toastr have it's own CSS and JavaScript files. You just need to references them correctly on your angular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to 12seconds for the input above, I just worked that out for myself using ng2-toasty.

I'm using webpack and I assumed that CSS was being imported automatically, I decided to copy the style sheets out of `node_modules\ng2-toasty` into my own folder `assets\ng-toasty` and put references into index.html.

My problem is now solved.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ng2-toasty/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ng2-toasty/style-bootstrap.css" />
```

[image]